# Why a loop is running three time in eclipse when the condition is false?

Tags: java, eclipse, loops

```
public class Menu {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws java.io.IOException {
        char choice;
        do {
            System.out.println("Help on:");
            System.out.println(" 1. if");
            System.out.println(" 2. while");
            System.out.println(" 3. do-while");
            System.out.println(" 4. for");
            System.out.println(" 5. switch");
            choice = (char) System.in.read();
        } while(choice < '1' || choice > '5');
    }

}
```

when i input 0 or greater than 5 it cause the loop to execute three time. like this:

```
Help on:
 1. if
 2. while
 3. do-while
 4. for
 5. switch
6
Help on:
 1. if
 2. while
 3. do-while
 4. for
 5. switch
Help on:
 1. if
 2. while
 3. do-while
 4. for
 5. switch
Help on:
 1. if
 2. while
 3. do-while
 4. for
 5. switch
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Check the while condition

Comment: The input will be `6` followed by the CR and LF characters so you go round the loop 3 times before it reads from the console again.

Comment: `System.out.printf("choice = 0x%x.%n", (int)choice);` and you will find `"\r\n"  too.

Comment: Consider to use the Scanner class

Answer (score 0):

Your while statement is a bit wrong and you are trying to use > and < with char witch doesn't work well using the Scanner class you can then use it to get the next int and then you can use it in the while statement.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int choice;
do {
    System.out.println("Help on:");
    System.out.println(" 1. if");
    System.out.println(" 2. while");
    System.out.println(" 3. do-while");
    System.out.println(" 4. for");
    System.out.println(" 5. switch");
    choice = scan.nextInt();
} while (choice >= 1 && choice <= 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you press 'enter' after entering '6' which is good, except, this means that there is an 'enter character' (which is a 'character' just as much as '6' is) in between your first input and your second, and the 'char value' is below '1'. On windows, an enter is in fact 2 characters (CR and LF; 13 and 10 respectively, which are far below `'1'`), hence, 3 loops.

Most likely you want a scanner configured to treat newline symbols as separators:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
s.useDelimiter("\\R"); // Any newline symbol
int c;
do {
  // show menu here
  c = s.nextInt();
} while (c >= 1 && c <= 5);
```

Alternatively, you can ignore newline symbols. These are '\r' and '\n' respectively. Replace `c = System.in.read();` with:

```
readNextChar();

.. below your main method:

public static char readNextChar() {
  while (true) {
    char c = System.in.read();
    if (c != '\r' && c != '\n') return c;
  }
}
```

Which will read the next char ignoring any newline symbols. (on windows, newline is '\r\n' - 2 characters in a row. On any other platform, it's just one '\n').